# Reparametrization of a contour integral problem with poles

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Referring to the above problem, I am confused as to how they re-parametrized and used Euler's formula to derive

$$\frac{-4iz}{(z^2 + 2az + 1)^2}dz$$

Doesn't letting $z = e^{i\theta}$ make the integral $\int_1^1$?

Any direction or walk-through would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Use $ cos $ formula $ cos(\theta) = (e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta))/2 $

Answer (score 1):

Use $ cos $ formula $ \cos(\theta) = (e^{i \theta} + e^{-i\theta})/2 = (z + z^{-1})/2 $